# T-Mobile G1 (MSM7200) GPU Memory

Tags: android, memory, opengl-es

I'm trying to find some information regarding the available GPU (for OpenGL) memory on the T-Mobile G1.

This phone has a MSM7200 Qualcomm chip inside with ATI Imageon GPU.

Unfortunately I am not able to dig any info regarding the specifics of GPU memory usage.

How much memory is available in total for the textures?
Is the memory shared with the CPU memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding the actual memory size - no new info.
but i did find out that the memory units of the GPU and CPU are separate. hope it helps someone...